# Most appropriate associative STL container when key is part of object [C++]

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, set, containers

I have a class like this:

```
struct Thing
{
    unsigned index;
    // more data members
};
```

I am using a `std::map<Thing>` to contain my `Thing`s.  Calling code looks something like this:

```
Thing myThing(/*...*/);
std::map<Thing> things;
things[myThing.index] = myThing;
// ...
Thing &thing3 = things[3];
```

I was wondering if there was an approach that could use `Thing::index` directly without the need implicitly to copy it into `pair::first`.

I guess I would need to provide some sort of `Thing` comparison operator, but that's OK.  `std::set` might work, but I would need a whole `Thing` object as key:

```
std::set<Thing> things;
Thing &thing3 = *things.find(Thing(3));
```

Other than refactoring `Thing` into a `std::pair`, can I do better with STL?

Comment: It's a good question; but if your key is just an integer, its not worth the trouble.

Comment: @K-ballo - You're probably right - and I could improve the calling code by writing a template wrapper around the `map` insert that acknowledges and abstracts the reference to `Thing::index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why

```
inline bool operator<(const Thing& a,const Thing& b) {
  return (a.index<b.index);
}

std::set<Thing> things;  // Uses comparison operator above

Thing &thing3 = *things.find(Thing(3));
```

doesn't do exactly what you want.  No duplication/copying of the index field, and key comparison as efficient as the map approach; what's not to like ?

**Update** in light of comments below:

If Thing is so heavyweight that you don't want to copy it, then you'd probably end up with code more like:

```
inline bool operator<(const shared_ptr<Thing>& a,const shared_ptr<Thing>& b) {
  return (a->index < b->index);
}

std::set<shared_ptr<Thing>> things;  // Uses comparison operator above

shared_ptr<Thing> key3(new Thing(3));   

Thing &thing3 = *things.find(key3);
```

although IMHO overriding pointer value comparison is fairly evil and it'd be better to go the more verbose route of an explicit "Compare" argument to the set template args.

One thing to bear in mind (from my own experience of big priority queues of heavyweight objects): there may be significant advantages to `std::pair<trivial_key,shared_ptr<heavyweight_object>>`-based containers over `std::pair<trivial_key,heavyweight_object>` due to the fact that traversals of the former touching only keys (e.g `find`) can be *much* more cache efficient compared with the latter which will also fetch a lot of mostly unneeded/irrelevant `heavyweight_object` bytes into cache (depends on the details and numbers of course, but in fact this effect could easily completely swamp the relatively minor cost of duplicating the key).

Comment: Because `Thing` may have other non-default constructible members, or members whose default construction is heavy (perhaps doing resource acquisition).

Comment: If Things are that heavyweight, you should probably be looking at a map or set of shared_ptr, or the boost "pointer containers".

Comment: `shared_ptr` won't help with the actual problem of having the key be part of the complex object value.

Comment: Also this means the whole object will be immutable.

Comment: @timday K-Ballo is right - Thing is heavyweight and we don't want a temporary `Thing(3)` if we can help it.  @UncleBens could you explain your comment?

Comment: Expanded my answer in light of comments.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap map with private inheritance or composition, reexport accessors and implement insertion in terms of required functionality. I'd recommend to patametrize your new type on key getter - a functor that returns a key given an object of storage type.

Comment: `struct Thing : private std::map { /*...*/ };` is a bad idea because `map`'s destructor may not be not virtual.  But otherwise a good idea.

Comment: The only reason to make inheritance private is to make sure that destructor of resulting type is virtual. If you are gonna leave virtual destructor out, it is easier to use public inheritance.

Comment: It's OK that `std::map`'s destructor isn't virtual with private inheritance. You only need a virtual destructor if you're going to say `delete BasePtr` where `BasePtr` is actually a pointer to `Derived`. Because you are using private inheritance, no one will be able to get a `std::map *` that actually points to a `Thing`.

Comment: @DavidStone: it is possible. Class methods and its friends are able to perform such cast.

Answer (score 1):

I Recall that [boost::flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/index.html) supports [key extractors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/key_value.html#key_extractor) to avoid keeping extra storage for the key, when it is readily obtainable from the object.

I'm not suggesting to use flyweight in all cases where `map` or `unordered_map` are sufficient, I have a hard time believing those classes won't support a similar key extraction pattern, although i can't find any mention in the docs or google. In either case this might be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

What about using the memory address of your object as a key in your map??

```
std::map< void*, std::shared_ptr<MyObject> > myMap;
myMap.insert( std::pair<void*, std::shared_ptr<MyObject> >(object.get(), object) );
```

So you don't need to store the key in your object which I think is a bad idea because the key does not has any relation with the objects state.

Comment: But then how do you find the `Thing` with `index == 3`?

Comment: You will never assign the index just keep the values of your pointers as indexes. Maybe void* in my pair is wrong and the better solution must be with MyObject* as key. anyway if you want for example to remove the object from your list you will pass the pointer of your object.

Comment: And if I don't have a pointer to the object outside the map? - Also, if the `index` member could just be removed from the struct, this question wouldn't exist.

Comment: Of course the index member must be removed in this case. I don't see the reason to keep the key as a member of object no any object in real world contain the index of this object, and also if you put this object in the second list will you make a new index as a member of this object? Memory address is a physical index which will guarantee that you never remove a wrong object from your list.